# Game project working on IDE, not working when I export it to JAR

Tags: java, jar, game-development

So this is a really simple question:

I am developing a game as a mere exercise. Game is almost complete, it's a really simple one. The point is, when I execute it from IDE (in this case, I'm using intelliJ), it works flawlessly. The problem comes when I try to produce an executable JAR file. The file just throws an error ("A Java Exception has occurred). Also, if I execute that same JAR file from the IDE, it works.

I've been trying to get it to work all the time, but it won't. I'll leave access to the code via Github, and if anyone want to try it, I would really appreciate it. Someone told me that it is most probably due to dependencies and external libraries not being included in the final JAR file. I only used one external dependency to produce and read a Json file, in order to keep a savegame for the highscores, but I think it's included on the final JAR file (at least, it's physically included, and I added the library before exporting the project).

This is the manifest for that dependency:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Automatic-Module-Name: org.json
Bnd-LastModified: 1677505062321
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_271
Built-By: stlea
Bundle-Description: JSON is a light-weight, language independent, data i
 nterchange format.        See http://www.JSON.org/        The files in 
 this package implement JSON encoders/decoders in Java.        It also i
 ncludes the capability to convert between JSON and XML, HTTP        hea
 ders, Cookies, and CDL.        This is a reference implementation. Ther
 e is a large number of JSON packages        in Java. Perhaps someday th
 e Java community will standardize on one. Until        then, choose car
 efully.
Bundle-License: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/LICENSE
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: JSON in Java
Bundle-SymbolicName: json
Bundle-Version: 20230227.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: org.json;version="20230227.0.0"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))"
Tool: Bnd-3.0.0.201509101326
```

I tried almost everything, but simply, Java doesn't wanna work.

**EDIT**

I was using a non compatible JDK, I solved it by downgrading my project to jdk 11.

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162311/a-java-exception-has-occurred-when-opening-jar

Comment: 1. Don't "leave links to code" - no body will follow them; 2. Include the full exception trace and at least the code snippet from which it was generated (the stack trace will provide this information)

Comment: Compare the java version used to run it from IntelliJ with java used from command prompt with: java -version. Run it from a command prompt to get more info: java -jar jarname.jar

Comment: @JohnWilliams the file was compiled on Java Runtime (class file version 63.0) while the version of java I have only recognizes class file versions up to 60.

Do you have any tip on how to compile the file on a lower version? Also, thank you all very much for your answers.

Comment: Try this - https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-change-java-version. You need jdk11. 60 is jdk16 but I’ve never heard of it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I was using an incorrect version of java ALL THE TIME. So now I'm correcting all the mistakes with my loader class, which didn't fully worked and I had to do a lot of stuff to overcome it. Stuff that now isn't working anymore, so I'm returning it to a previous state.

Again, thanks @JohnWilliams

Comment: I have generated an answer from the comments. Please accept it. Its useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that you using different JVM versions - the IntelliJ compiling to a JVM version higher that that being used elsewhere.

The mappings between [JVM Versions and JDK versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)

You can check this by comparing the java version used to run it from IntelliJ with java used from command prompt with: java -version. Run the jar from a command prompt to get more info: java -jar jarname.jar.

You then need to reduce the INtelliJ version [like this](https://baeldung.com/intellij-change-java-version.) or increase the other version by installing a newer JRE.